# CSV to MYSQL parse issue

Tags: php, mysql, regex, csv

I am trying to parse a .csv file into a mysql database, and it's not fun.

Some rows look like this:

"Value", Value, "Value3", ,"Value,Value"

And some look like this:

Value, Value, , Value, , Value

This preg_split worked well except for fields that were empty:

```
foreach ($row as $item) {
     $item = preg_split( "/[,]*\\\"([^\\\"]+)\\\"[,]*|[,]+/", $item, 0, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE|PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

When I removed "PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY", I got an extra, empty value added at the end of $item.
Is there a regex expression that would work for this?

Comment: You might be able to make your life easier using existing functionality in MySQL, like Load Data Infile: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not use [LOAD DATA INFILE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html)

Alternatively, use PHP's built in [fgetcsv()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) or [str_getcsv()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) functions rather than messing about with regular expressions trying to reinvent the wheel

Comment: +1. Don't write your own CSV parser. It's harder than you think. You'll get it wrong.